# Laravel Backpack CRUD gives 404 Failed to Load Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I just installed Backpack in my Laravel project. I followed the steps, but I get a 404 error.

```php
class PostCrudController extends CrudController
{
    public function setup()
    {
        /* CrudPanel Basic Information */

        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Post');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/post');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('post', 'posts');

        /* CrudPanel Configuration */

        // TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Fields and Columns
        $this->crud->setFromDb();

        // add asterisk for fields that are required in PostRequest
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(StoreRequest::class, 'create');
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(UpdateRequest::class, 'edit');
    }
}
```

**custom.php route**

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => ['web', config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')],
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () { // custom admin routes
    CRUD::resource('Post', 'PostCrudController');
}); // this should be the absolute last line of this file
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi there - your setup looks pretty basic, and I can't see a reason for it to throw a 404, I'm afraid. Please go through the error stack and see where exactly the 404 is thrown - what file and what line, and what that line says. That should help us track down the issue. Very weird....

Comment: I just found the problem. I had no indication of where the error was. It was just the Post who needed to be post. That's all. I feel foolish now, but I found it.Thank you!